# Is there a way to check if any content of a array is in another array in Roblox

Tags: arrays, lua, roblox

So I am trying to make a script which allows me to ban people but the main script which checks if a player is in the game *and* in the banned users list to be killed or kicked. Here is my code:

```
local BannedUsers = {"littleBitsman"}
local Players = game.Players:GetChildren()
wait(10)
for index1,value1 in ipairs(Players) do
    for index2,value2 in ipairs(BannedUsers) do
        if Players[index1] == BannedUsers[tonumber(index2)] then
            local HumanoidToKill = workspace[value1].Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
            if HumanoidToKill.Health >= 0 then
                HumanoidToKill.Health = 0
                print("killed " .. tostring(value1))
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The `wait(10)` is so I can test the script without executing too early, and the use of my username is for testing.
Also when I do test it it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `table.find` function.

```lua
local BannedUsers = {"littleBitsman"}

for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
     if table.find(BannedUsers, player.Name) then
          player:Kick("You are banned!")
     end
end
```